# LiveData not triggered when Room database is updated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-room, android-livedata

I have a `ViewPager` with 2 fragments. When the list is updated on one fragment, it should reflect that change on the other fragment.

This is how my `Dao` methods looks like for updating

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ${Constants.KAFANI_TABLE_NAME} WHERE isFavorite = 1")
fun getFavoriteKafani(): Single<MutableList<Kafana>>
@Query("UPDATE ${Constants.KAFANI_TABLE_NAME} SET isFavorite = :isFavorite WHERE id = :id")
fun setFavourite(id: Int, isFavorite: Int)
```

Then, I call these methods inside my `repository`

```
fun getFavoriteKafani(): Single<MutableList<Kafana>> {
    return kafanaDao.getFavoriteKafani()
}
fun setKafanaFavorite(kafana: Kafana, isFavorite: Int): Completable = Completable.fromCallable {
    kafanaDao.setFavourite(kafana.id, isFavorite)
}
```

My `ViewModel`

```
fun setFavorite(kafana: Kafana, isFavorite: Int) {
    compositeDisposable.addAll(kafanaRepository
            .setKafanaFavorite(kafana, isFavorite)
            .compose(scheduler.getSchedulersForCompletable())
            .subscribeBy(
                    onComplete = {
                        sendFavoriteUpdate(1)
                        Timber.d("${Constants.KAFANA_APP_TAG} Added as favorite ${kafana.name}")
                    },
                    onError = {
                        Timber.d("${Constants.KAFANA_APP_TAG} setFavorite onError ${it.localizedMessage}")
                    }
            ))

}

fun loadFavoriteKafani() {
    compositeDisposable.addAll(kafanaRepository
            .getFavoriteKafani()
            .compose(scheduler.getSchedulersForSingle())
            .subscribeBy(
                    onSuccess = {
                        if (it.isEmpty()) {
                            isFavoriteEmpty.set(true)
                            Timber.d("${Constants.KAFANA_APP_TAG} loadFavoriteKafani listIsEmpty")
                        } else {
                            kafaniList.value = it
                            isFavoriteEmpty.set(false)
                            Timber.d("${Constants.KAFANA_APP_TAG} loadFavoriteKafani listNotEmpty")
                        }
                    },
                    onError = {
                        isFavoriteEmpty.set(true)
                        Timber.d("${Constants.KAFANA_APP_TAG} loadFavoriteKafani OnError: $it.localizedMessage")
                    }))
}
```

And finally in my `fragment`

```
private fun getFavoriteKafani() {
    viewModel.loadFavoriteKafani()
    viewModel.kafaniList.observe(this, Observer<MutableList<Kafana>> {
        it?.let {
            sorted = it.sortedWith(compareBy({ !it.isSponsored }, { it.name })).toMutableList()
            kafanaAdapter = KafanaAdapter(sorted, this, 2)
            binder.rvKafani.adapter = kafanaAdapter
        }
    })
}
```

But whenever I set kafana as favorite in one fragment, the list is not triggered in the other one.

Comment: did you try, just for testing, `kafanaRepository.getFavoriteKafani().observe(...)`?

Comment: Nope, I haven't. Should I be returning LiveData from the repository?

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-observable

Comment: but most likely you should see [PagedListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedListAdapter)

Comment: @pskink Yes, it works. But do you have any idea how can I implement it with RxJava? I can build an `RxPagedListBuilder` but how do I handle errors? Also, this way it seems like I'm skipping the `repository` layer.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/ and https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/data